# How to calculate big O notation according to number width?

Tags: complexity, big-o, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand big O with the bitwise operations. I have 2 functions those are solving the same question from different perspective.

`num1BitsSecondSolution` starts to shift the number right until number is 0. So Complexity looks like = O(width(n)) but how could I notate `width` ?

`num1BitsThirdSolution` it is more complex to calculate it's respected complexity because it just do `number = number & (number - 1)` which is based on number's initial bit representation form. Example : If there are 4 "1" bits in the number then complexity is `O(4)` so how could I explain these in Big O ?

```
function num1BitsSecondSolution($number)
{
    if ($number <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for ($c = 0; $number; $number >>= 1) {
        $c += $number & 1;
    }

    return $c;
}

function num1BitsThirdSolution($number)
{
    if ($number <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for ($c = 0; $number; $c++) {
        $number &= $number - 1;
    }

    return $c;
}
```

Comment: "Number Width" you could try `log base 2`. That will give you (approximately) the left most digit position.

Comment: yes but how do you explain number width with O notation ?

Comment: It's pretty standard. `O(log(n))`.

Comment: I understand O(log(n)) but I didn't realize log(n)'s complexity itself o(log(n)) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(log n) where n is the size of the number. The two functions have the same complexity, since they each perform an operation pr bit. The second example may be faster depending on the actual bits, but big-O notation is calculated for the worst case, which is this case would be a number with only 1-bits.